# Why can't I locate ProgressiveMediaSource?

Tags: java, android, exoplayer2.x

Looking at [the ExoPlayer documentation](https://exoplayer.dev/hello-world.html), the "Hello World" example suggests that to play a standard video you should use a `ProgressiveMediaSource` (compared to many online tutorials I've seen suggesting you use an `ExtractorMediaSource`)

Looking at the [source code for ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/library/core/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/source/ExtractorMediaSource.java), it claims that `ExtractorMediaSource` is deprecated, and `ProgressiveMediaSource` has replaced it:

```
/** @deprecated Use {@link ProgressiveMediaSource} instead. */
```

In my own project I'm using ExoPlayer v2.9.5 -- [which is the latest version on jcenter, released February 2019](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.exoplayer/exoplayer)

Yet when I try to instantiate a `ProgressiveMediaSource`, I get the error:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'ProgressiveMediaSource'
```

Why can I not locate this class? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image: JCenter List]

I found that by clicking on this tab, newer versions of ExoPlayer were listed.

`ProgressiveMediaSource` was added in version 2.10.0

However version 2.10.0 also made the switch from the Android Support Library to AndroidX, so you will have to upgrade your whole project to AndroidX if you wish to use it.