# How to make ProgressiveMediaSource usable in ExoPlayer? Symbol not found

Tags: java, android, exoplayer, cannot-find-symbol

I am working on a project where I am trying to implement ExoPlayer to replace a VideoView. My issue is that I am getting this error: `cannot find symbol class ProgressiveMediaSource`

I have seen [Why can't I locate ProgressiveMediaSource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56118614/why-cant-i-locate-progressivemediasource) and note that it is mentioned that ProgressiveMediaPlayer was added in ExoPlayer 2.10.0 - I am using 2.10.1 so version shouldn't be an issue. The other condition that was mentioned was having the Android project upgraded to AndroidX. I believe that I am only using AndroidX unless one of my dependencies is importing some support libraries (com.android.support).

The compiler throws an error on import:

```
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaSource;
```

If providing my gradle build script would help, let me know.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Error was due to human transcription error. I had typed progessive instead of progressive and never noticed until much later

Lesson: if a symbol can't be found, make sure you spelled it correctly.